# Прокрутка компонента с массивом рисованных прямоугольников в PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qscrollarea, paintevent

Никак не получается сделать прокрутку.

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor


class TableComponents(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.table = []
        super().__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        paint = QPainter(self)
        # paint.begin(self)

        height = 20
        width = 20
        interval = 25
        i = 0
        j = 0

        while i < 100:
            while j < 100:
                paint.setBrush(QColor(50, 150, 50, 255))
                paint.drawRect(i * interval + 10, j * interval + 10, height, width)
                j += 1

            j = 0
            i += 1


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        tc = TableComponents()

        scroll = QScrollArea(self)
        scroll.setGeometry(0, 0, 1400, 800)
        scroll.setWidget(tc)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(scroll)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = App()
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle('App')
    mainWindow.setGeometry(50, 50, 1200, 800)
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: У меня [подобная проблема](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/master/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt__QPainter__FlowWidget.py) была -- нужно было переопределить и возвращать значения из `minimumSizeHint` и `minimumSize`, чтобы `QScrollArea` добавила ползунки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QSize


class TableComponents(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.table = []
        super().__init__()

    def paintEvent(self, QPaintEvent):
        paint = QPainter(self)
        # paint.begin(self)

        height = 20
        width = 20
        interval = 25
        i = 0
        j = 0

        while i < 25:
            while j < 25:
                paint.setBrush(QColor(50, 150, 50, 255))
                paint.drawRect(i * interval + 10, j * interval + 10, height, width)
                j += 1

            j = 0
            i += 1

    def sizeHint(self):                                  # <--- sizeHint
        return QSize(500, 500)


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        tc = TableComponents()

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()  # self
#        scroll.setGeometry(0, 0, 1400, 800)
        self.scroll.setWidget(tc)
#        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = App()
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle('App')
#    mainWindow.setGeometry(50, 50, 1200, 800)
    mainWindow.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]